# Cannot get channels moving event in Discord audit log

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to log the Discord event when someone is moving any channel.
The channelUpdate event works almost like a charm and returning 2 events (two, because of when you moving one channel the rawPosition property is changing in the target's channel and in the channel you swiped the place). Except strange cases when you moved one channel and getting tone of events as if you moved all the server channels at ones. Weird thing, yep.

The problem is the "channelUpdate" event returns only oldChannel and newChannel but not the executor data (who and when).

I've tried to use guild.fetchAuditLogs({ type: 14, limit: 1 }) but looks like it's not returning changing position events. One gets the feeling Discord's log engine is not logging this event OR I'm looking in wrong place. Also tried type 11  and even NULL with no luck on finding rawPosition prop changing.

Please, help me to find the way how to log WHO is changing the channels position or tell me it's not possible at the time.

Some code here:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ shards: 'auto'});
const { prefix, token, witaitoken , guildID, DBUser, DBPass } = require('./config.json');

client.on('ready', async () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    client.user.setActivity(`Star Citizen`, { type: 'PLAYING' });
});

client.on('channelUpdate', (oldChannel, newChannel) => {
    if (oldChannel.rawPosition !== newChannel.rawPosition) {
        oldChannel.guild.fetchAuditLogs({ limit: 10 })
            .then( (audit) => {
                const log = audit.entries;
                if (!log) return;
                fs = require('fs');
                fs.appendFile('audit.txt', JSON.stringify(log), function (err) {
                        if (err) return console.log(err);
                    });
        })
    }

});

client.login(token);
client.on("error", (e) => console.error(e));
client.on("warn", (e) => console.warn(e));
client.on("debug", (e) => console.info(e));
```

Comment: We'll need to see some code, can you show how you're fetching the audit logs

Comment: @Elitezen [shure](https://github.com/Tolarion/djs/blob/main/robot.js)

Comment: @Garoo please edit your question to include the relevant code. It is generally best practice on StackOverflow to include just the relevant code directly in the question as opposed to an image or link to your code.